# Why state management libraries use react's context for dependency injection?

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, react-redux, mobx-react

I looked at the source code of two famous state management libraries for React and find out that both of them use React's context as a dependency container ([Mobx `Provider`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/master/src/Provider.js#L20), [Redux `Provider`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js#L26)). 
On the other hand, I find it a good practice to try to not use React related constructs for libraries (specially context) and I think it is possible to create a separate module for dependency container. Here is a naive implementation of my thoughts:

```
let container = {};

const register = (obj) => {
  Object.assign(container, obj);
}

const getAll = () => container;

export { getAll, register };
```

Am I missing something? Is there any edge cases that cannot be supported by just using a module? Why they use context as the dependency container in React?

Answer (score 0):

Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level. This helps these libraries to take control over the entire application components by wrapping it up with their additional functionalities.

Although Sebastian Markbage, React Team had mentioned about The Context API not built considering for high frequency updates.

check out the link for more information: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite/issues/62

Try [Rootz JS](https://rootzjs.org)